# Example code to connect log events from GCP Composer V2 to Cloud Logging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

Is there any example code on how to log events from Cloud Composer to Cloud Logging ?

I have tried to add the logger in the following way -

Logger Setup

```
import logging
from google.cloud import logging as cloud_logging
```

Based on docs calling `logging_client.setup_logging()` should configure logging to Google Cloud Logging but that doesnt seem to be happening.

I am unable to find the logging statements I have added in the DAG in Cloud Logging.